# Someone knows about instaloader request limits?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, instaloader

I'm doing an Instagram scraper (specifically I'm extracting the data of the following accounts from a primary account) and the program sends me an exception error:[image: exception error]

The program only scrapes 200 following accounts and that happens, when the program tries automatically after 30 minutes, prompting an error, so I concluded that I only can extract 200 following accounts per hour, someone knows about it?

Here is the code [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have used a for loop to request data in instaloader.Profile.from_username(). this for loop hit so many request to server within seconds which can not handle by PC. you should keep a time.sleep() of 0.1 to 0.5 second or more in for loop. it will works.